# Can't bind to 'chart' since it isn't a known property of 'apx-chart'

Tags: angular, apexcharts, ng-apexcharts

I've been trying to solve this problem since 2 days..

I want to use apexcharts with angular 7.1.0 (the latest version of apexcharts and ng-apexcharts is not working, only version 3.15.2 for apexcharts & 1.5.0 for ng-apexcharts are working with me).

The error :

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'series' since it isn't a known property of 'apx-chart'.
1. If 'apx-chart' is an Angular component and it has 'series' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'apx-chart' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("           <div id="chart">
                                                            <apx-chart [ERROR ->][series]="chartOptions.series"
                                                                     "): ng:///MainModule/DashboardComponent.html@653:71
Can't bind to 'chart' since it isn't a known property of 'apx-chart'.
1. If 'apx-chart' is an Angular component and it has 'chart' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'apx-chart' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("ries]="chartOptions.series"
                                                                       [ERROR ->][chart]="chartOptions.chart"
                                                                       "): ng:///MainModule/DashboardComponent.html@654:71
Can't bind to 'dataLabels' since it isn't a known property of 'apx-chart'.
1. If 'apx-chart' is an Angular component and it has 'dataLabels' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'apx-chart' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("chart]="chartOptions.chart"
                                                                       [ERROR ->][dataLabels]="chartOptions.dataLabels"
                                                             "): ng:///MainModule/DashboardComponent.html@655:71
Can't bind to 'plotOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'apx-chart'.
1. If 'apx-chart' is an Angular component and it has 'plotOptions' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'apx-chart' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("]="chartOptions.dataLabels"
                                                                       [ERROR ->][plotOptions]="chartOptions.plotOptions"
                                                           "): ng:///MainModule/DashboardComponent.html@656:71
Can't bind to 'yaxis' since it isn't a known property of 'apx-chart'.
1. If 'apx-chart' is an Angular component and it has 'yaxis' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'apx-chart' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("="chartOptions.plotOptions"
                                                                       [ERROR ->][yaxis]="chartOptions.yaxis"
                                                                       "): ng:///MainModule/DashboardComponent.html@657:71
Can't bind to 'xaxis' since it isn't a known property of 'apx-chart'.
1. If 'apx-chart' is an Angular component and it has 'xaxis' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'apx-chart' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("yaxis]="chartOptions.yaxis"
                                                                       [ERROR ->][xaxis]="chartOptions.xaxis"
                                                                       "): ng:///MainModule/DashboardComponent.html@658:71
Can't bind to 'fill' since it isn't a known property of 'apx-chart'.
1. If 'apx-chart' is an Angular component and it has 'fill' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'apx-chart' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("xaxis]="chartOptions.xaxis"
                                                                       [ERROR ->][fill]="chartOptions.fill"
                                                                       [t"): ng:///MainModule/DashboardComponent.html@659:71
'apx-chart' is not a known element:
1. If 'apx-chart' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'apx-chart' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("                      <div id="chart">
                                                            [ERROR ->]<apx-chart [series]="chartOptions.series"
                                                          "): ng:///MainModule/DashboardComponent.html@653:60
Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'series' since it isn't a known property of 'apx-chart'.
1. If 'apx-chart' is an Angular component and it has 'series' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'apx-chart' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("           <div id="chart">
                                                            <apx-chart [ERROR ->][series]="chartOptions.series"
                                                                     "): ng:///MainModule/DashboardComponent.html@653:71
Can't bind to 'chart' since it isn't a known property of 'apx-chart'.
1. If 'apx-chart' is an Angular component and it has 'chart' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'apx-chart' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("ries]="chartOptions.series"
                                                                       [ERROR ->][chart]="chartOptions.chart"
                                                                       "): ng:///MainModule/DashboardComponent.html@654:71
Can't bind to 'dataLabels' since it isn't a known property of 'apx-chart'.
1. If 'apx-chart' is an Angular component and it has 'dataLabels' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'apx-chart' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("chart]="chartOptions.chart"
                                                                       [ERROR ->][dataLabels]="chartOptions.dataLabels"
                                                             "): ng:///MainModule/DashboardComponent.html@655:71
Can't bind to 'plotOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'apx-chart'.
1. If 'apx-chart' is an Angular component and it has 'plotOptions' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'apx-chart' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("]="chartOptions.dataLabels"
                                                                       [ERROR ->][plotOptions]="chartOptions.plotOptions"
                                                           "): ng:///MainModule/DashboardComponent.html@656:71
Can't bind to 'yaxis' since it isn't a known property of 'apx-chart'.
1. If 'apx-chart' is an Angular component and it has 'yaxis' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'apx-chart' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("="chartOptions.plotOptions"
                                                                       [ERROR ->][yaxis]="chartOptions.yaxis"
                                                                       "): ng:///MainModule/DashboardComponent.html@657:71
Can't bind to 'xaxis' since it isn't a known property of 'apx-chart'.
1. If 'apx-chart' is an Angular component and it has 'xaxis' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'apx-chart' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("yaxis]="chartOptions.yaxis"
                                                                       [ERROR ->][xaxis]="chartOptions.xaxis"
                                                                       "): ng:///MainModule/DashboardComponent.html@658:71
Can't bind to 'fill' since it isn't a known property of 'apx-chart'.
1. If 'apx-chart' is an Angular component and it has 'fill' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'apx-chart' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("xaxis]="chartOptions.xaxis"
                                                                       [ERROR ->][fill]="chartOptions.fill"
                                                                       [t"): ng:///MainModule/DashboardComponent.html@659:71
'apx-chart' is not a known element:
1. If 'apx-chart' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'apx-chart' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("                      <div id="chart">
                                                            [ERROR ->]<apx-chart [series]="chartOptions.series"
                                                          "): ng:///MainModule/DashboardComponent.html@653:60
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2430:1)
    at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:20605:1)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:26171:1)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:26158:1)
    at compiler.js:26101:48
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:26101:1)
    at compiler.js:26011:1
    at Object.then (compiler.js:2421:33)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:26010:1)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:831:1)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:788:1)
    at zone.js:892:1
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422:1)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195:1)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601:1)
```

My code

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgApexchartsModule } from "ng-apexcharts";
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, NgApexchartsModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import {
  ApexAxisChartSeries,
  ApexChart,
  ChartComponent,
  ApexDataLabels,
  ApexPlotOptions,
  ApexYAxis,
  ApexTitleSubtitle,
  ApexXAxis,
  ApexFill
} from "ng-apexcharts";

export type ChartOptions = {
  series: ApexAxisChartSeries;
  chart: ApexChart;
  dataLabels: ApexDataLabels;
  plotOptions: ApexPlotOptions;
  yaxis: ApexYAxis;
  xaxis: ApexXAxis;
  fill: ApexFill;
  title: ApexTitleSubtitle;
};
export class theCharts implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('chart') chart: ChartComponent = {} as ChartComponent;
    public chartOptions: Partial<any> = {} as Partial<any>;

    constructor() {
       
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.chartOptions = {
            series: [
                {
                    name: "Inflation",
                    data: [2.3, 3.1, 4.0, 10.1, 4.0, 3.6, 3.2, 2.3, 1.4, 0.8, 0.5, 0.2]
                }
            ],
            chart: {
                height: 350,
                type: "bar"
            },
            plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        position: "top" // top, center, bottom
                    }
                }
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function (val) {
                    return val + "%";
                },
                offsetY: -20,
                style: {
                    fontSize: "12px",
                    colors: ["#304758"]
                }
            },

            xaxis: {
                categories: [
                    "Jan",
                    "Feb",
                    "Mar",
                    "Apr",
                    "May",
                    "Jun",
                    "Jul",
                    "Aug",
                    "Sep",
                    "Oct",
                    "Nov",
                    "Dec"
                ],
                position: "top",
                labels: {
                    offsetY: -18
                },
                axisBorder: {
                    show: false
                },
                axisTicks: {
                    show: false
                },
                crosshairs: {
                    fill: {
                        type: "gradient",
                        gradient: {
                            colorFrom: "#D8E3F0",
                            colorTo: "#BED1E6",
                            stops: [0, 100],
                            opacityFrom: 0.4,
                            opacityTo: 0.5
                        }
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    enabled: true,
                    offsetY: -35
                }
            },
            fill: {
                type: "gradient",
                gradient: {
                    shade: "light",
                    type: "horizontal",
                    shadeIntensity: 0.25,
                    gradientToColors: undefined,
                    inverseColors: true,
                    opacityFrom: 1,
                    opacityTo: 1,
                    stops: [50, 0, 100, 100]
                }
            },
            yaxis: {
                axisBorder: {
                    show: false
                },
                axisTicks: {
                    show: false
                },
                labels: {
                    show: false,
                    formatter: function (val) {
                        return val + "%";
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: "Monthly Inflation in Argentina, 2002",
                offsetY: 320,
                align: "center",
                style: {
                    color: "#444"
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div id="chart">
  <apx-chart
    [series]="chartOptions.series"
    [chart]="chartOptions.chart"
    [dataLabels]="chartOptions.dataLabels"
    [plotOptions]="chartOptions.plotOptions"
    [yaxis]="chartOptions.yaxis"
    [xaxis]="chartOptions.xaxis"
    [fill]="chartOptions.fill"
    [title]="chartOptions.title"
  ></apx-chart>
</div>
```

**What i tried**

- https://github.com/apexcharts/ng-apexcharts/issues/197
- https://github.com/apexcharts/ng-apexcharts/issues/190
- And other related and non-related topics across google.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: is it correct that this `export class theCharts implements OnInit {` is your AppComponent?

Where is the components decorator?

Comment: @DenisLoh You mean like that `export class AppComponent {` ?

Comment: Yes, in your code above, there is no `export class AppComponent` and thus I was confused, if there is something essentially missing. Is this the full code example?

Comment: @DenisLoh, yup, i forgot to export the class inside the main AppComponent and inside constructor super(injector) .. its working now.